# Admin 403 Forbidden Errors

Tags: admin

I'm running into a strange problem.  I have a site that is managed by a client.  A couple of days ago, they started noticing that things weren't working correctly in the admin.  I checked it and found that there were errors showing up in the dev console.  Here are the errors I get on the admin landing page:

> NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - ...admin.php?S=11606155886845716ce19d7cdde155fc5d604080&D=cp&C=javascript&M=load&file=css&theme=default&v=1312216958

> NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - ...admin.php?S=11606155886845716ce19d7cdde155fc5d604080&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,sortable,dialog&plugin=ee_focus,ee_notice,ee_txtarea,tablesorter,ee_navigation&file=cp/global&effect=core&v=1312216960

> NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - ...admin.php?S=11606155886845716ce19d7cdde155fc5d604080&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&file=cp/homepage&v=1312216960

> NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - ...admin.php?S=11606155886845716ce19d7cdde155fc5d604080&D=cp&C=javascript&M=load&file=css&theme=default&v=1312216958

> NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - ...admin.php?S=11606155886845716ce19d7cdde155fc5d604080&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,sortable,dialog&plugin=ee_focus,ee_notice,ee_txtarea,tablesorter,ee_navigation&file=cp/global&effect=core&v=1312216960

> NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - ...admin.php?S=11606155886845716ce19d7cdde155fc5d604080&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&file=cp/homepage&v=1312216960

All JavaScript interaction is killed (dropdown menus, tabs, etc.), and it happens in all browsers. I've checked all the file permissions that I'm sure about and they haven't changed.  As far as I know, nothing has been touched for a long time on the server. The client makes frequent updates to the site, but I don't see how they'd be able to cause such errors.

Granted, it's an older version (v 2.2.2), but it's been working fine up until a few days ago.  Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Nevermind, folks. After finding the same thing happening on another site, hosted on the same server, I've determined it was a change in the server config by the host. Currently working it out with them.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue in EE 2.5.3 - I thought updating to 2.6.1 would resolve things, however it has not. All permissions and paths are correct. Did your host ever respond with what the issue is?

Comment: We use Eleven2 for hosting (we HATE them and are trying to get all of our sites moved to another host ASAP). Without warning, they made some security changes to our server. I'm not a "server guy", so I don't understand all of what happened, but we were told that they added "mod_security", which caused the 403 errors. They told us they "removed mod_security" from each of our hosted sites and everything worked again. Hope that helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had this problem when my hosting provider, Eleven2, updated our shared hosting server's configuration. The problem seems to be "mod_security" blocking these requests.

To fix the problem disable mod_security in your .htaccess file by adding the following lines:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That's good to know.  Thanks, Alex!