# 501 Method Not Implemented error on Nexcess

Tags: categories

Heyo everyone,

I'm getting a 501 Method Not Implemented error when saving a specific entry. Screenshot: http://d.pr/i/VeFj

After some googling it looks like a mod_security issue. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

The entry is called "Deus Caritas Est" so it is possible that mod_security is having a conflict with the entry title. I've issued a support request with Nexcess, but wanted to know if anyone else had see that issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had to contact Nexcess support to allow a mod_security exception for our site. Hope this helps anybody else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have have this happen and [**others have as well**](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/search?q=mod_security)... Usually comes up as a 403 Forbidden error.

[**Alex Roper**](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/16668/28) posted this code for disabling in the .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```